# How to set up Multiple networks and routing using new Ubuntu Netplan?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, netplan

I have a requirement and this was working (up to 2020) without issue.  As my installs were outdated and I didn't care to actually UPGRADE, I decided to blitz the lot and begin with fresh installs using Ubuntu 23.04 for servers and 24.04 for my desktop.

I am creating this via Virtualbox setup and have two host-only networks: 192.168.110.x and 192.168.120.x. Any server installs will be in either 110 or 120.

The desktop has 3 NICs:

- `enp0s3`=NAT (10.0.2.15)
- `enp0s8`=192.168.110.3
- `enp0s9`=192.168.120.3.

I have set IP forwarding on the desktop to route 110 and 120 through `enp0s3` using IP tables.

All this was working when `gateway` was a valid declaration in netplan. However, now the setup is different, I have been looking at the netplan examples provided via a different question and can find nothing which might match MY needs.  I am finding it a bit confusing to work out the routing declarations for each network.

As an aside, rather than declaring nameservers twice, can I somehow just specify it once for all ethernets?

```
  1 # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
  2 network:
  3   version: 2
  4   renderer: NetworkManager
  5   ethernets:
  6     enp0s8: #Edit this line according to your network interface name.
  7       dhcp4: no
  8       addresses:
  9         - 192.168.110.3/24
 10         routes:
 11         - to: default
 12           via: 192.168.110.1
 13       nameservers:
 14         addresses:
 15           - 8.8.8.8
 16           - 8.8.4.4
 17     enp0s9: #Edit this line according to your network interface name.
 18       dhcp4: no
 19       addresses:
 20         - 192.168.120.3/24
 21         routes:
 22         - to: default
 23           via: 192.168.120.1
 24       nameservers:
 25         addresses:
 26           - 8.8.8.8
 27           - 8.8.4.4
 28
```

The error I am getting is:

> Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please
> set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
>
> Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main,
> metric: default), first declared in enp0s8 but also in enp0s9

Comment: Having multiple default routes doesn't make any sense: the default route is the route of last resort and there can be only one. You would run into a similar error if you were to try to manually add multiple default routes using `ip route add`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. The old method was simple: NIC address, netmask, gateway.  I am a bit confused with this new method as to what 'gateway' is now defined as.

Comment: A default route has to be associated with an interface. A global "gateway" setting didn't make sense because it wasn't associated with an interface. If you previously had a single "gateway", then now **one** of your interfaces would define a default route.